# convert Creole to LaTeX

Tags: python, latex, restructuredtext, pandoc, creole

Care to recommend a tool/workflow(s) for converting [Creole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creole_(markup)) wiki pages/files to [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)?

I'm a grad student who has been documenting code and analyses using (a number of) wikis, mostly using Creole syntax. I like Creole, but eventually I'll need to write an article, for which I'll need to generate LaTeX. Is there a tool that will do that directly and competently? If not, what's the next-best, least-effort, highest-quality indirect path? Some things that came to mind are:

1. [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/): supports LaTeX for both input or output, but does not support Creole for either input or output. (Am I missing something?)
2. [reStructuredText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText): I know Pandoc supports reST for both input or output, and of course it's widely used with Python, so I'm starting to use reST for new wikis. But I'm not seeing a [Creole -> reST converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292217/convert-creole-to-restructuredtext). (Am I missing something?)
3. HTML: Pandoc supports HTML for both input and output, as I'm sure do a zillion other tools, including [python-creole](http://code.google.com/p/python-creole/). So `Creole >python-creole> HTML >Pandoc> LaTeX` seems feasible (am I missing something?) but indirect.

Comment: The only way to find out if to try it. In my experience, translators work right only for reasonably simple uses, and tend to fail miserably for complex stuff. Two unrelated translators in a row is asking for a miracle... Better bit the bullet and learn LaTeX, you'll need it anyhow.

Comment: I can already write LaTeX, but will hafta write a ton of it for the article anyway, and would vastly prefer not to hafta rewrite the wiki-managed content as well.

Comment: A paper is some ten pages, retyping that  (or just talking the text and editing the commands) can't be *such* a chore...

Comment: The article may be 10 pages, but what about the 'Supplementary information', 'Supporting materials', etc? Anyway, I'd much rather spend my time doing, e.g., graphics and analysis than rekeying markup.

Answer (score -1):

Pandoc offers a Creole2Latex interface as can be [tested online](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try/). However Creole is called *Haddock Markup* there.

Comment: @user149229: When I look at [documentation for Creole markup](http://www.wikicreole.org/wiki/Home), and compare that to [documentation for Haddock markup](http://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/ch03s08.html), I see *lots* of differences.